# Google App Engine quota reached on test site. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-app-engine

First off, I'm totally new to GAE. 3 days ago I did a search on Google for hosting a website on Google App Engine for free. I found this tutorial on labnol.org:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-app-engine/18801/

I was under the impression that GAE's quota for free users was high. My site has received very little traffic. At best, the site is getting 50 daily page views, of which most, if not all, are mine. I'm testing my code on and refreshing my browser.

GAE indicates the following: Frontend Instance Hours - 100% - 28.00 of 28.00 Instance Hours

I made no adjustments to my GAE settings UNTIL this morning. 2 things changed in the last 12 hours:

1. I changed my frontend instance class from the default f1 to f4. My reason for doing so was to see if it would improve my site's loading time (it didn't). My site is a fairly small and simple site.
2. I replaced the html files and images from the last 2 days with fresh ones this morning. Doing this resulted in my making some changes to files and uploading (deploying via GoogleAppEngineLauncher Mac app) changes probably about 5 times per hour.

On my settings page everything is at 0, with the exception of this one:

Frontend Instance Hours      100%    28.00 of 28.00 Instance Hours

How did I reach the hosting quota for GAE? Should I adjust any other settings? What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Additional facts:

- The size of the folder containing all my files is 38kb in size.
- I have Google Analytics, by way of Javascript, running on index.html (none of the other pages).
- I'm using raw, basic, html.
- my pages consist of approximately 3kb of image data being served per page.

Thanks

Comment: You just increased your instance class to one that's four times the size of the default. It shouldn't be surprising that that blew through your free quota fairly quickly.

Answer (score 5):

If your website consists of largely static content, I *highly* recommend you implement [Frontend Caching](http://www.kyle-jensen.com/proxy-caching-on-google-appengine).  This should drastically cut down your instance hours as the majority of it would be served off Google's **frontend** servers.

For every page that's served from cache, you'll see a 204 logged in AppEngine.  See also [this](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/scaling-app-engine-applications.html) talk on scaling GAE apps.

Note that there's also the option of using `memcache` within your app, but briefly looking at that tutorial link, I suspect this won't apply to you.

Answer (score 3):

> I changed my frontend instance class from the default f1 to f4.

F4 class instances consume hours 4 times faster. Your 28 hour quota will get exhausted every 7 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using that much instance time serving 50 static pages, I'd guess that your idle instance setting is set at 1 or more (which would make the app run all day even when no one is using it).  Make sure that on your application settings page the "idle instances" slider is set at "automatic-1".

Answer (score 1):

He will not be able to adjust his Idle Instance setting until enabling billing.